# How to grab a string inside a pandas dataframe using a regex

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to regex out a certain string inside my pandas df.
Say I have a df like so:

```
         a                  b
0  foo foo AA123 bar        4
1  foo foo BB245 bar        5
2  foo CA234 bar bar        5
```

How would I get this df:

```
     a          b
0  AA123        4
1  BB245        5
2  CA234        5
```

One method I tried was `df.replace({'(\w{3}\d{3})': ?})` but wasn't sure what to put for the second parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the regex-based [Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function to keep just the matching group. You also need a fix to your regex - the cardinality for the `\w` elements should be 2. In the end the code would be:

```
df["a"] = df["a"].str.extract('(\w{2}\d{3})', expand=False)
```

The `expand=False` is to indicate you don't want `str.extract` to return a `DataFrame`, which it does by default in order to accommodate multiple regex groups (it returns one column per group). Since you already know there is just one regex group here, for convenience you specify `expand=False` to get back a `Series` you can immediately assign to `df["a"]`. If there were more than one regex group, the function would return a `DataFrame` no matter what you specified for `expand`, and you would index into it to get the column/group you wanted.

Comment: I think it should be \w{2}, based on the data

Comment: Agreed - just found same by testing. Will update. Thx.